# How to send a FB request with Javascript sdk entering a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would send a request with FB.ui when the user enter to a particular .php page.

I use this script to async loading the javascript SDK:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

// Additional initialization code here
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function sendRequestToRecipients(user_id) {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
      to: user_id, 
    }, requestCallback);
  }
</script>
```

Then, I try to call the function sendRequestToRecipients() inside the  tag with onLoad function:

```
<body onLoad="sendRequestToRecipients('0000'); return false;">
```

But I receive 2 errors "Unexpected identifier", and nothing happens.

Also, if I delete the onload from body and I manually call the sendRequestToRecipients function with a button

```
<input type="button"
    onclick="sendRequestToRecipients('0000'); return false;"
    value="Send"
  />
```

Everything goes perfectly!

Any help??

Answer (score 2):

You can't call that from the *onload* event since you can only make api requests once the facebook sdk finished loading and initializing.

It should be:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
            channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        sendRequestToRecipients("USER_ID");
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

    function sendRequestToRecipients(user_id) {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'My Great Request',
            to: user_id, 
        }, requestCallback);
    }
</script>
```

Notice that I called *sendRequestToRecipients* in the *window.fbAsyncInit* callback method, after the *FB.init*.